# How can I get the sink trap to clear the drawer under my bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, sink, p-trap

Is there a better solution to a P-Trap? We have installed a new vanity only to find that the drawer contacts the p-trap.

The vanity has 3 drawers. The top one is built in a "u-shape" and goes around the drain pipes. But, the next one down still hits the P-Trap:

[image]

My other attempt was to use a flexible P-Trap and angel it to the side, But I don't know that this would actually work.

[image]

I'm really trying to avoid cutting a notch out of the back of the drawer if possible.Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Stuff tends to get stuck in the accordion pleats of those flexible ones. Can you provide a wider angle shot of your first pic where the drawer is hitting the trap? It _might_ be possible to shorten the tail piece so the trap is higher. You'd probably have fewer drain problems, though, if you just cut a notch out of the drawer.

Comment: In the first pic, the drawer actually is in contact with the pipe. It would be less than 2" or so. just wanted to avoid doing that. But might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a notch in the back of your drawer. If you do it carefully with a hole saw or jigsaw it'll just clear the pipe and not look terrible. I like to make the notch and then run a router with a roundover bit around it.

The only other option is to raise the drain inlet in the wall.

Comment: I did find this, but I'm very skeptical of it.  https://hepvo.com/hepvo-waterless-valve/

Comment: Used a hole cutter. Worked like a charm.